# PowerShell: How to get the name of my ESXi

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere, esxi, hypervisor

How to get the ESXI Name?
what I tried:

```
Add-PsSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core -ErrorAction  "SilentlyContinue"
$User = 
$Password = 
$ESXiServer = "IPAddress"
Connect-VIServer $ESXiServer -User $User -Password $Password 

$Datacenter = Get-Datacenter
$Datastore = Get-Datastore
$DataStoreLocation = $Datastore.ExtensionData.info.url  
$Datastore = Get-Datastore
```

"`get-vm`" gives me the VMs which are on m Hyper-V. 
"`get-vmhost`" gives me the name of my Computer.

I do not know how to get the name of my ESXI server!!

EDIT:

found a command which gives me ESXi name but do not know how to extract just the "name" Information

```
Get-MvmcSourceVirtualMachine -SourceConnection $sourceConnection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get my ESXi name by this command:

```
(Get-MvmcSourceVirtualMachine -SourceConnection $sourceconnection).Name
```

Answer (score 0):

*get-vmhost* returns ESXi server object information
 *(get-vmhost ($global:DefaultVIServer).name )).extensiondata.name*  should give you the esxi server name

Comment: The result is an IPaddress which is the same as : $ESXiServer = "IPAddress"

Comment: how about (get-vmhost ($global:DefaultVIServer).name )).extentiondata.name

Comment: mine is in german. I have translated for you: get-vmhost :   Mindestens ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:2
+ (get-vmhost ($global:DefaultVIServer).name ).extentiondata.name
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-VMHost], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unspecified,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVMHost . at least there is an Error is translation of Mindestens ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.

Comment: there was a typo in my reply - 'extention' instead of 'extension'

Comment: same Error: get-vmhost : Mindestens ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:2
+ (get-vmhost ($global:DefaultVIServer).name ).ExtentionData.name
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-VMHost], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unspecified,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVMHost

Comment: you did not change the command "($global:DefaultVIServer).name ).ExtentionData.name"

Comment: "(($global:DefaultVIServer).name ).ExtentionData.name" is empty. gives me no result!

Comment: Please use extenSiondata

Comment: "(($global:DefaultVIServer).name ).extenSiondata.name" gives me also no result

Comment: Can you see the output   of (get-vmhost ($global:DefaultVIServer).name )).extensiondata ?

Comment: no. It has Error. I have edited my question. can you please Check.

Comment: it would be helpful to describe the environment you use. Get-MvmcSourceVirtualMachine  is virtual machine conversion cmdlet.

Comment: Thats why I need the VM(ESXi) name. when i run this command: Get-MvmcSourceVirtualMachine -SourceConnection $sourceConnection  i can see its name. but do not know how to extract the name